# using nested arrays by php http_build_query() and recieve them in flash AS3

Tags: php, actionscript-3, urlencode, multidimensional-array

i am having this hard time figuring what is needed to do, 
i am using URLVariables to send/recieve values between flash and PHP

the problem is, i am unable to access nested arrays ( array inside an array ) with flash

heres an example:

$dgresult = array("total" => $results);
echo http_build_query($dgresult,"flf_");

in flash, all i need to do is to use:
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);

then i can access it with :
variables.total

the problem now is when i have nested arrays:

$dgresult = array("total" => $results);
array_push($dgresult,$another_array);
http_build_query($dgresult,"flf_");

i can still access variables.total

but what about anything that has flf_ ?
how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to simply use established formats for complex data, such as [JSON](http://json.org/). For PHP see [here](http://gggeek.altervista.org/sw/article_20061113.html) and for AS3 see [here](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/). Or ready made solutions such as [AMFPHP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/amfphp/).

greetz
back2dos

Comment: Right, i have used JSON functions to enhance the output to an acceptable level in Flash. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

or you can just parse the object

```
var url:String = 'http://localhost/dump.php';
var params:Object = {
    test: 'ok',
    nested_1: {
        nested_2: {
            nested_3: {
                nested_4: {
                    hello: 'mf',
                    str: '~!@#$%^&*()_+'
                }
            }
        }
    },
};

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

parameters = fixParameters(parameters || {});

for (var key:String in parameters) {
    variables[key] = parameters[key];
}

request.data = variables;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(request);
```

and here is fixParameters method

```
private function fixParameters(data:Object, parameters:Object = null, prefixes:Array = null):Object {
    var setPrefix:Array;
    var prefixKey:String;

    if (!parameters) {
        parameters = {};
    }

    if (!prefixes) {
        prefixes = [];
    }

    for (var key:String in data) {
        setPrefix = prefixes.concat([key]);

        if (typeof(data[key]) == 'object') {
            parameters = fixParameters(data[key], parameters, setPrefix);
        } else {
            prefixKey = '';
            for (var i:Number = 0; i < setPrefix.length; i++) {
                prefixKey += i == 0 ? setPrefix[i] :  '[' + setPrefix[i] + ']';
            }
            parameters[prefixKey] = data[key];
        }
    }

    return parameters;
}
```